# How can show pdf preview first image?

Tags: 8, theming

Hope you can help me.

I use drupal 8.

I want pdf preview like this http://prntscr.com/j08ljo.

[image]

Need uploud pdf file in node and showing just first image in front page.

I check use module pdfpreview https://www.drupal.org/project/pdfpreview

Have with tutorial and dependence. Setup ImageMagick and configured it in image toolkit.
Sent in server files with imagemagick and write path.

"Path to the package executables" ... http://prntscr.com/j08ogh

[image]

After this showing in display manage full content "pdf preview" http://prntscr.com/j08r9i
[image]
But nothing happened. I hear about "may be i need install for other way imagemagick"

Can you help me?

Thanks for your future answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to firstly install imagemagick in your operating system.
for Ubuntu please follow below procedure:-

(1)https://medium.com/@sanjaywrites/install-latest-version-of-imagemagick-in-ubuntu-16-04-c406ddea1973

(2) https://www.enovate.co.uk/blog/2015/12/16/how-to-install-imagemagick-from-source-on-ubuntu-14.04

For window download imagemagic exe file.
https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

once your Operating System have magicmagick  then install these module pdfpreview https://www.drupal.org/project/pdfpreview

and do a needful change as shown in image[image]

and on your view  do a needful change as shown in image

[image]